# TableViewCell with Autolayout constraint issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, constraints, autolayout

I've been trying for 2 days in a row to fix a custom cell I created. I'm new to iOS, so I've been reading that I **must** set constraint if **use autolayout** is enabled.

Even though I set some constraints, the issue is still there, so I'm guessing either ways the iOS Simulator has a bug I'm not aware of, or there was something missing in the 10+ guides & tutorials I have already read. Yes, I made my research, I've read several articles including:

- [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) (this one seems to be the more complete one)

The custom cell is being created in the storyboard, here's a picture containing the contraints:

(The `UIImageView`'s **view mode** is set to `center`)

[image]

And here's a picture of the `iOS Simulator`:

[image]

**EDIT:** I also deleted all constraints, but the result is the same, the iOS Simulator renders it the same way

**SOLUTION:** This is so stupid, my `UIImageView` pointer was called `*imageView` and it seems `UITableViewCell` has a pointer with the same name so whenever I called it, mine was being ignored, and instead was called the superclass' one, resulting not in what I thought it was a resize issue, but a superposition

Comment: Your tableview has constraint errors.  Click on the little red circle to the right of "Events Table View Controller Scene" and fix them. After you've fixed and updated your constraints then all the constraints should be blue.

Answer (score -1):

Try selecting the UIImageView, opening up the inspector tab, and checking if the UIImageView is set to "Clip Subviews".